# scroll bar css in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, browser-scrollbars

i want to apply css for scroll bar in internet explorer:

i had used below css for the just a particular scroll bar

```
.ui-menu {
    scrollbar-track-color: #C0C0C0;
    scrollbar-base-color: #797979;
}
```

even in that i want to remove scroll bar arrows....which i couldn't..

i did this for google chrome and safari using below css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 12px;
    width: 18px;
    background: #C0C0C0;
    }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #797979;    
}
```

it worked fine ..............

so my requirement is i want remove the arrows and display only track and thumb for scroll bar in IE......globalise for whole site ..........

atleast if not possible i want that have to be worked for particular scroll bar on a page in IE..........

any work around plz...............

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, This feature is not supported by IE (applying css to scrollbars)

Comment: u mean cannot apply css for scrollbar in IE or cannot generalise for entire site

Comment: you cannot apply css for scrollbars in IE

Comment: but i am able to give some color stuff css. do u have any document that says it,if so can i have it for reference plz......

Comment: i got it from w3schools website while searching a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors of scrollbars in IE but as far as I see there is no style for hiding arrows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772048(v=vs.85).aspx